# where does parameters get stored in Request Object?

Tags: java, http, debugging, servlets, request

I have following line of code

```
request.getParameter("email");
```

while debugging when I inspect this line I get the desired value, but when I inspect whole **request** object I cant see this value in my **ParameterMap**.

Where to get these values in request object

I am using tomcat 6.0.34 as container

Comment: The answer is going to depend on which container you are using. Please also provide the full version number.

Comment: Do you inspect the whole request object before you call request.getParameter() or after? The parameter map is populated lazily so it will be empty until there is a call to getParameter() (or one of the other related methods).

Answer (score 1):

```
Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. 
For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data. If the parameter data was sent in the request body, then i occurs with an HTTP POST request.
```

In an HTTP GET request, parameters are sent as a query string:

```
http://example.com/page?parameter=value&also=another
```

check this for more information

```
Data from the query string and the post body are aggregated into the request parameter set. Query string data is presented BEFORE post body data. For example, if a request is made with a query string of a=hello and a post body of a=goodbye&a=world, the resulting parameter set would be ordered a=(hello, goodbye, world).

The following are the conditions that must be met before post FORM data will be populated to the parameter set:

The request is an HTTP or HTTPS request.

The HTTP method is POST.

The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

The servlet has made an initial call of any of the 'getParameter' family of methods on the request object.

If the conditions are not met and the post form data is not included in the parameter set, the post data must still be available to the servlet via the request object's input stream. If the conditions are met, post form data will no longer be available for reading directly from the request object's input stream.
```

http://www.javacertifications.net/javacert/HttpservletRequest.jsp

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/what-is-the-difference-between-the-request-attribute-and-request-parameter/1